# Can't install pandas==1.3.0 (python 3.8) `Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 1.3.0`

Tags: python, pandas, pycharm, anaconda, requirements.txt

I was using `pandas 1.2.1` and it works but I want to upgrade it to `1.3.0` to use some new features, but when I try to do `pip install pandas==1.3.0`, it gave me an error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement 1.3.0
ERROR: No matching distribution found for 1.3.0
```

(I'm using PyCharm with a conda virtual env, Python 3.8)

Then when I check the version, it's only been upgraded to `1.2.5`, does anyone know what's going on here and how can I resolve this? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to install by using `conda` command and it works now

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade Pandas using conda command

```
conda update pandas
```